# Same component works when defined through @component but it fails when created with create_component_from_func

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a `Docker` container in `gcloud` with all the code I need (multiple files, etc.). I'm able to run it when I defined the component using the `@component` decorator. I define the function and I set up the `base_image`. The component does a few things and it loads code from the container as expected.

However, It fails when I create the component through a function. First, I create the component with the `create_component_from_func` function (same function, and I define the same container). Then I use it.

Then I create a pipeline with those 2 components (in the example they are just 2 components disconnected). I would expect the same result from both components, but the 2nd fails. It cannot import the functions. I did some prints and checks (even reading the code itself) and it is there. Everything looks exactly the same. I thought those were analogous approaches, and I guess they are not.

Any idea of the differences and why it works with `@component` but not for `create_component_from_func`

This is obviously not the code (I would need to provide a container, etc.) but you can get an idea of what I'm doing:

```py
from kfp.components import create_component_from_func
from kfp.v2.dsl component

def add_values_from_func(a:int, b:int) -> int:
    # I can do stuff and print
    from container_file import transformer_function
    return transformer_function(a) + transformer_function(b)

@component(base_image="my_docker_image_in_gcloud")
def add_values(a:int, b:int) -> int:
    # I can do stuff and print
    from container_file import transformer_function
    return transformer_function(a) + transformer_function(b)


# PIPELINE CODE
### This component works
add_values_task = (
    add_values(a=1, b=2)
)

### This component errors out saying that it cannot find the transformer_function
add_values_from_func_component = create_component_from_func(
    func=add_values_from_func,
    base_image="my_docker_image_in_gcloud",
)
add_values_from_func_component_task = (
    add_values_from_func_component(a=1, b=2)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the PYTHONPATH is different when you define a container through `@component` or through `create_component_from_func`.

The WORKDIR is not included for the second case.

So there are some solutions:

- Adding `ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${WORKDIR}"` to the Dockerfile
- Adding it at the beginning of the component: `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that @component is more recent and [recommended](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/sdk-v2/v2-component-io/#use-v2-component-decorator-for-python-function-based-components) for Python function-based components. It's hard to say why one works and the other doesn't without more information about your code. However, I suggest you check if the container image is correctly defined in both cases.

Comment: problem was PYTHONPATH is different one way or another. I put an answer myself to the issue. Dockerfile is created by `kfp` in both approaches, I only added the `base_image` (same) for both.